# How to calculate $ \frac{d}{dt}(\int_{0}^{t} \sin(x^2)\,dx)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

$$ \frac{d}{dt}(\int_{0}^{t} \sin(x^2)\,dx)$$

I only need to know if it is zero or not at $$t=0$$ $$t=\pm \pi$$ $$t=\pm 2\pi$$ ... Don't need to calculate the integral

Hint says use Leibniz rule but I couldn't use it.

Comment: Use the 1st fundamental theorem of integral calculus.

Comment: So it is just $sin(t^2)$?

Comment: Yes, exactly$.$

Comment: bounds of the integral don't matter?

Comment: They matter if they're variable.

Comment: So the upper bound is $t$ this is why I directly wrote $sin(t^2)$ ? and the lower bound is just a number it doesn't matter if it is $0$ or $1$ or $5$?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the problem correctly?

Comment: Yes. Geometrically, it is rather intuitive. Also for a bit mre complex case, note that, for instance, $\int_0^{\sqrt t}\sin   x^2\,\mathrm dx$ is a composition of functions of $t$ and is differentiated as such.

Comment: I am actually trying to find if derivative of $\alpha(t) = ((\int_{0}^{t} \sin(x^2)\,dx), cos(t))$ can be zero. So, I can say at $t=0$  $\alpha'(t) = 0$ right?

Comment: Yes, but clearly, there's a single solution: you should have both $\sin t^2=0$ and $-\sin t=0$, i.e. $t^2\equiv 0$ and $t\equiv 0\mod\pi\mathbf Z$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FTOC, and you will obtain $\sin(t^2)$, then just evaluate at your test points.